# Layout inside another layout is not accessible from the activity

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have multiple layouts that are defined in hierarchical order, The issue is when i try to access item that is defined in an inner layout, it gives me `NullPointerException`.

This is my layout structure.

```
 R.layout.activity_map
->   <include layout="content_map"> 
->   <include layout="terrace_parent_map"> 
->   <include layout="terrace_collection_map">
```

Now `terrace_collection_map` has constraint layout, that i need to access from the activity. 
Following is the layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/constraintTerraceLayout"
    >


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But when i try to get id of `constraintLayout`, it returns null.

```
 constraintTerraceLayout= findViewById(R.id.constraintTerraceLayout);
```

**Edit - terrace_collection_map **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/constraintTerraceLayout"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView30"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/terrace" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Confirm that your `ConstraintLayout` of `terrace_collection_map.xml` starts and ends with `<merge>` tag or it has an own root view.

Comment: @Android : I have edited my answer please check, i am not using <merge> tag.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts read this to use `<merge>` tag, if activity map has `linearLayout` as a parent tag. Use `<merge>` tag as parent before `ConstraintLayout` in terrace_collection_map.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my problem, please add this as an answer

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding the `<merge /`> tag that helps you to eliminate redundant view groups in your view hierarchy when including one layout within another.

For example, if your main layout is a vertical `LinearLayout` in which two consecutive views can be re-used in multiple layouts, then the re-usable `layout` in which you place the two views requires its own root view.

So use `<merge>` tag, if `activity_map.xml` has `LinearLayout` as a parent tag. Then change your `terrace_collection_map.xml` parent tag as like below code :

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 //..........Your Custom Layout Design...........
</merge>
```

This link helps you briefly, https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts